# Error using read.exif to read image metadata in R

Tags: r, image, metadata

I am getting errors when trying to use read.exif to read image metadata in R (more detail can be found about read.exif here https://github.com/MarcusRowcliffe/CTtracking/blob/master/CTtracking.r)

**My code is:**

```
folder <- "./TEST"
dep.exdat <- read.exif(folder, tagfield="Keywords")
```

**The error is get is:**

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "rowid", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  replacement has 30 rows, data has 13
In addition: Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here and how I can fix it?

All the images in the TEST folder have been tagged using XnView.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `exifr` package

```
require( exifr )

folder <- "./TEST"
Keywords <- c( "filename", "imagesize" )
dep.exdat <- exifr::read_exif(
    path
  , tags = Keywords
  , recursive = FALSE
  , args = NULL
  , quiet = TRUE
)
```